# Angular 4 datatable dynamic routerLink

Tags: angular

Suppose I have an API that returns a list of users with a structure like this:

```
{
  aaData: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'John Doe'
    },
    {
      id:2,
      name: 'Doe John'
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

This is then processed and fed to `datatables`.

How can I convert name to a clickable link with `routerLink`?

Have tried turning the `name` like: `<a [routerLink]=['/user/1']>John Doe</a>`, but it rendered as `<a routerlink="/users/1">John Doe</a>` instead and nothing happens when clicked.

Another option is to iterate all the `a` and bind `router.navigate` but would like to see if there're better ways to do it.

Comment: Did you include the RouterModule?

Comment: Yup, I did. I think the reason it doesn't work is because its using the jQuery datatables. I'll be binding it manually to `router.navigate` for now if there's no way to make it work with `routerLink`.

Comment: do have `<router-outlet>` in components `.html` file?

Comment: Yup I do have `<router-outlet>` too. Actually I tried manually binding the `<a>` tag with `router.navigate` and it works. Was a hackish POC, and will have to clean it up though.